# Django rest framework update related FileField of a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I have these models:

```
class House(models.model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class HouseImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='images')
```

And this serializers:

```
class HouseImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HouseImage
        fields = ('image', )

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = HouseImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('address', 'images', )
```

And this view:

```
class HouseDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
    queryset = House.objects.all()
```

I am making to calls from my frontend. One creates the House (and it works) and the second one is supposed to send the images. Therefore, in the second call I am making a PATCH request (with axios) and my `request.data` is `{'images': [InMemoryUploadedFile1, InMemoryUploadedFile2,...]}`

Questions:

1. Am I doing correct so far by defining the `images` field on `HouseSerializer`? If it's correct, what else should I do? Because I know I need to somehow map each of the image in `images` list in my `request.data` to the `image` field in `HouseImage`.
2. Is there a better approach in implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

de facto you did not `patch` you `House` model, you try to create new `HouseImage`, so in my mind best way is new APIView for `HouseImage` model.

in serializers:

```
class HouseImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HouseImage
        fields = ('image', 'house')
        #                   ^^^^^^
```

in view

```
class HouseImageDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = HouseImageSerializer
    queryset = HouseImage.objects.all()
```

in `HouseSerializer` you will have extra field `house` in the `images` does it matter?

for your case you can try to override the `update`

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = HouseImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('address', 'images', )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        images = request.data.get('images', []) if request else []
        for img in images:
            data = {'image': img, 'house': instance}
            hiSerializer = HouseImageSerializer(data)
            if hiSerializer.is_valid():
                hiSerializer.save()
        return super(HouseSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: But supposing it's not a patch, is there no way to update models and their foreign keys with a single call(single view)?